# All wildcard subdomain traffic to SSL and custom domains to non-SSL HTTP on Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, http

I'm running a server on a Laravel Forge (Nginx) setup. I'm creating a site builder where the user has `username.sitebuilder.com` (not my real domain) with the ability to have `www.whatever.com` mapped over it, which was all working fine.

However, I needed to add an SSL wildcard cert for *.sitebuilder.com and that is working correctly for all *.sitebuilder.com traffic. But I need the server to still listen to www.whatever.com (not SSL) and that's no longer working after adding the cert.

How do I setup Nginx to route to:

- *.sitebuilder.com -> SSL
- www.whatever.com -> HTTP

When I go to www.whatever.com I get the `Welcome to nginx!` page and not the expected website.

Here is my config file:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/sitebuilder.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ~.;

    #add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    #add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    #add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/sitebuilder.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/sitebuilder.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .sitebuilder.com;
    root /home/forge/sitebuilder.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sitebuilder.com/00000/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sitebuilder.com/00000/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers '**PRIVATE KEY**';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    #add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    #add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    #add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/sitebuilder.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/sitebuilder.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/sitebuilder.com/after/*;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `server_name` for `whatever.com` as `~.` effectively matches anything and I assume sitebuilder actually handles the hostname response.

Comment: I fixed it, I forgot to add `root /home/forge/sitebuilder.com/public;` under `server_name`. However, out of curiosity, I think the Nginx file, currently seems a little messy.

Comment: That's a fairly straightforward nginx config, there isn't really much you can improve. As I say, I would be inclined to have a separate server section for a different domain for clarity but that's just style.

Comment: Glad there's not too much to improve on. I understand that you mean regarding a separate server section, but users could run into the 100's (maybe 1000's) so I'll use this format for now. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Just to clarify, I meant your example of `*.sitebuilder.com` vs `whatever.com`. Your wildcard is fine for your customer namespace.